# A hot water tank contains exactly 96 liters of water (GMAT math)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A hot water tank contains exactly 96 liters of water. After taking a shower there is exactly 4 liters less in the hot water tank than the amount of water which was extracted. How much water was used for the shower?

1. 50
2. 40
3. 96
4. 10
5. 4

We call x the quantity of water used in liters. And we know that x-4 liters remains. But I don't see how we can find x. ?

Comment: Please tag the question correctly as this requires zero calculus at all.  What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$96 - x = x-4$

Use this equation, and you'll get the answer.